# Index(of:) and Equatable Protocol

Tags: swift, indexof, equatable

```
class Person: Equatable {
var name: String
var age: Int

init(name: String, age: Int) {
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
}
static func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
    return (lhs.name == rhs.name) && (lhs.age == rhs.age)
}
}
let p1 = Person(name: "David", age: 29)
let p2 = Person (name: "John", age: 28)

var people = [Person]()
people.append(p1)
people.append(p2)

let p1index = people.index(of: p1)
let p2index = people.index(of: p2)
```

In order to use `index(of:)`, i need to conform Person to Equatable protocol. From what i know, Equatable protocol allows 2 instances to be compared for equality. What is the relation between finding an index and compare for equality? Why I must conform to Equatable protocol in order to use `index(of:)`?

To adopt the Equatable protocol, I must implement the `(==)` operator as a static method:

```
static func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
    return (lhs.name == rhs.name) && (lhs.age == rhs.age)
}
```

I am not comparing any Person instances for equality here, why do I still need to `return (lhs.name == rhs.name) && (lhs.age == rhs.age)`? What is it for? Does it have anything to do with `index(of:)`?

Sorry for asking this stupid question.

Comment: Does [the implementation of `index(of:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/CollectionAlgorithms.swift.gyb#L64) answer your question? :)

Comment: Although I'm not sure I understand the second part of your question, "*I am not comparing any Person instances for equality here*" – yes you are, you're comparing `lhs`'s properties with `rhs`'s properties.

Comment: It helps. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask yourself this: what does `index(of:)` do exactly?

It finds the index of the specified element in the array. Right? In other words, *it finds the index of the first element that is equal to the parameter*.

A simple implementation for `index(of:)` would be to loop through the array and in each iteration, check whether the element is equal to the parameter. If it is, return the index. As you can see, this involves checking whether two objects are equal, so the `Equatable` protocol is required.

Comment: Now i understand. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

> **indexOf(:)** in this case, required to confirm Equatable protocol.

NOTE:

- As indexOf(:) iterate array and compare your passed object to every element in the array which indirectly comparing and returning the index of matched object.

For eg:

```
let p1index = people.index(of: p1)
```

Here, p1index can find by comparing it to every element in the people array and return the index **by comparing properties of p1 object** match ***with*** properties of the **object in the people array** at that particular index.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `class Person: NSObject` if you don't want to add additional protocol methods.